# char val = 'abcd'. Using multi character char

Tags: c++, char

I have a confusion of how the compiler handles a char variable with multiple characters. I understand that a char is 1 byte and it can contain one character like ASCII.

But when I try:

```
char _val = 'ab';
char _val = 'abc';
char _val = 'abcd';
```

They compiles fine and when I print _val it always prints the last character. But when I did

```
char _val = 'abcde';
```

Then I got a compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2015: too many characters in constant

So my questions are:

1. Why does the compiler always takes the last character when multiple characters are used? What is the compiler mechanism in this situation.
2. Why did I get a too many characters error when I put 5 characters. 2 characters is more than what a char can handle so why 5?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you.

Comment: On 1: "always", no, it's implementation defined. Different compilers will do different things (but always the same thing).

Comment: Probably because 4 `char`s are the size of 1 `int` (on most platforms, including yours). So an `int` value can be calculated from any sequence of up to 4 `char`s. Then, in order to assign this `int` value into a `char` variable, it is truncated to the size of `char` (so only the "least significant" `char` is copied).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[lex.ccon]/1:

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>   *multicharacter literal*. A multicharacter literal [..] **is conditionally-supported, has type `int`, and
>   has an implementation-defined value.**

---

> Why does the compiler always takes the last character when multiple
>   characters are used? What is the compiler mechanism in this situation.

Most compilers just shift the character values together in order: That way the last character occupies the least significant byte, the penultimate character occupies the byte next to the least significant one, and so forth.
I.e. `'abc'` would be equivalent to `'c' + ((int)'b')<<8) + (((int)'a')<<16)` ([**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b3b0b359be59a3e)).

Converting this `int` back to a `char` will have an implementation defined value - that might just emerge from taking the value of the `int` modulo 256. That would simply give you the last character.

> Why did I get a too many characters error when I put 5 characters. 2
>   characters is more than what a char can handle so why 5?

Because on your machine an `int` is probably four bytes large. If the above is indeed the way your compiler arranges multicharacter constants in, he cannot put five `char` values into an `int`.